# Postgres times: wrong conversion with time zones

Tags: postgresql

Let's assume that we have some date, for example `2018-06-25T06:00:00Z`. So, in case I do the following I get the same date:

```
select '2018-06-25T06:00:00Z'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC';
```

Now, I want to get local time for this date and as I am located in Helsinki I do the following:

```
select '2018-06-25T06:00:00Z'::timestamp at time zone 'Europe/Helsinki';
```

As I know that Helsinki is currently +3 hours my expectation is to get `2018-06-25 09:00:00.000000`, however, for some reason I get `2018-06-25 03:00:00.000000`.

***So, why it decided to deduct this 3 hours instead of adding them?***

Note, that this `select current_setting('timezone')` returns `UTC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second statement interprets the given timestamp as timestamp in the time zone Europe/Helsinki and converts it to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`. `psql` prints the result of the timestamp according the the `SESSION TIMEZONE`.

To convert your timestamp from UTC to Europe/Helsinki, you should use a timestamp with time zone:

```
SELECT '2018-06-25T06:00:00Z'::TIMESTAMPTZ AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Helsinki';
```

This will create a timestamp and convert it to Europe/Helsinki. You may change the time zone for output with:

```
SET SESSION TIMEZONE TO 'Europe/Helsinki';
```